# Does Beacon Notification Can wake up terminated app

Tags: android, ios

I have project need to add notifications with Beacons。I have some questions wanna to make sure.

1. does os can receive beacon notification without APP running?
2. Can we show different showing content depend on different beacon notification?
3. can we open terminated app by beacon notification?
4. can the app do different behavior depend by the beacon notification content after start up?

Thanks。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-** **How beacon works**

> The Android Beacon Library can launch your app into the background to
>   start looking for beacons after the phone boots. This will happen
>   transparently with no visible user interface, while the rest of your
>   app remains idle.
>
> Once the desired beacon is detected, a callback method fires where you
>   can push a custom notification message. You can further configure the
>   notification so it launches a specific part of your app when pressed.

**2- different notification**

Yes ! each beacon has its id and you can handle showing different notification depending on the id and also different content

**3- lunching app**

Yes !  you can add your logic in the services that handle beacon notification method to start the preferred activity.

**WARNING**: launching a UI without any user interaction is a very very bad practice for most of the applications!

> [...] Interrupting what the user is currently doing is considered bad
>   design form, especially from something that is supposed to be
>   operating in the background. Therefore, you should consider using a
>   Notification [...] to launch the desired Activity when the user
>   decides it is time to investigate. [...]

**4- App behavior**

Yes ! all you have to do is setting your `pendingIntent` accordingly to the notification